# Is there an aperiodic tiling consisting of deformed hexagons?

Tags: tiling

The typical Penrose tiling consists of two deformed quadrangles. But it's there any aperiodic tiling consisting entirely of two or more deformed hexagons? Maybe even one that shares some properties of a hexagonal tiling such as only edge-neighbours?

Comment: How about the chair tiling?

Comment: @DanielRust interesting, though [it](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution_rules/chair) fails on true aperiodicity

Comment: What's your definition of aperiodicity then? Most take it to mean an FLC non-periodic tiling that is also repetitive (all with respect to translation). The chair tiling satisfies these properties.

Comment: @DanielRust maybe I missed something up there, is the Penrose tiling also repetitive?

Comment: Yes. The usual substitution has primitive associated substitution matrix and so it is repetitive (i.e. its associated translational dynamical system is minimal).

Comment: I should add there are many different definitions of aperiodic tiling, and also an aperiodic *set* of tiles. So when I asked for your definition it wasn't a rhetorical question, it's perfectly reasonable to consider a different definition.

Comment: @DanielRust I see. So the chair tiling is definitely a valid answer

Comment: It would depend on what you're using it for I guess :). With a quick browse of the (admittedly lacking) [table of aperiodic sets of tiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aperiodic_sets_of_tiles#List), it looks like the Ammann A2 tiles might also be suitable. As with the chair tiles, I don't think this tileset forces aperiodicity without the local matching rules (the decorations on the tiles) but the *tiling* given by these matching rules is certainly aperiodic.

Comment: You may be interested in this: [An aperiodic hexagonal tile](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4279). It is jut one tile, rather than 2, but they do mirror it, too. Anyway, might provide some good food for thought.

Comment: @jwd Sounds great, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use the [Penrose Rhombus Tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling#Rhombus_tiling) as a start.  The edges with a round bump, use a straight line. Those with the triangle, use two lines.
[image]

Comment: nice, thanks. I wonder if there something similar can be achieved with purely convex hexagons, and whether edge-only neighbours are possible